# Adding a generated image stream in sendgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, sendgrid

Sendgrid's api allows adding embedded image in emails with a method. However the method accepts file path and image cid name as inputs. My problem is the image i'm trying to embed is a base64 steam generated with user input and due to shared hosting restrictions i'm unable to save it. Is there a way to accomplish my task of embedding the image without actually saving it. It's a mvc application with c#.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could you specify the file path as `data:image/png;base64,<your base64 data here...>`?

Comment: Are you using the sendgrid-csharp library? There is an overload for adding an attachment directly from a stream. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/e75eaee35beaf9170505db626408021c50307289/SendGrid/SendGridMail/SendGrid.cs#L277

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin I tried doing that but for some reason, the image does not show up in the email.

Comment: @bwest I'll give this a try and check if works

Comment: @bwest the method senda an image but no valid image is visible in the email